# substituting nth character of a field with awk

Tags: awk

I have a file that looks like this

```
seq1 CT 5 CCCGCTGCTGATGAC  
seq2 AG 8 CTGTGTAGATGATGGGTTAGAG  
seq3 TG 3 CGTGTGACA
```

I am trying to replace the nth character of field 4 with the string in field 2, where n= value specified by field 3. The output would be

```
seq1 CT 5 CCCGCTTGCTGATGAC  
seq2 AG 8 CTGTGTAAGATGATGGGTTAGAG  
seq3 TG 3 CGTGGTGACA
```

my attempt looks like this

```
awk '{a=$3; b=$2; sub(/(substr($4, a, 1))/,b);  print $0}’
```

I guess what is happening is that it is treating whats specified by sub command as a string rather than get the string specified by substr command, and variable b. After searching I can’t find the correct way of doing this.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{$4 = substr($4, 1, $3-1) $2 substr($4, $3+1); print}'
```